# assign integers to strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, multidimensional-array

Is there a way in C to assign strings with integers.

I have a 2d array of strings and I know its already assigned with indexes but I want to assign each with a random number like an id.
I don't know if I should do this after submitting it into an array or when I am reading messages directly.

I would like to have something like this

2d array:

```
john  
michael  
simon
```

What I want:

```
john - 234  
michael - 432  
simon - 489
```

My function code to insert names into an array

```
int store(char *stock){


    int r;
    static char test[5][10];
    static int i=0;
    int k,j=0;  


    //this just copies names from another function
    strcpy(test[i], stock);
    printf("%s in index:%d\n",test[i],i);

    qsort(test, i, 10, cmp);    
    if (i==4)
    {

        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("%s\n",test[j]);
        }
    }
    i++;

}
```

thanks

Comment: Can you use `sprintf`?

Comment: you could create a seperate array that held the integers in the same index as the name in the original array (use row indexes).

Comment: While the two static variables will probably work for you in your current scenario, be aware that it is a most unusual way of organizing your code and will lead to trouble if you use it in most other situations.  Also, your code exhibits O(N*N*log(N)) complexity, which doesn't matter much for N=5 but would matter a lot in other scenarios.  Also, you don't check for buffer overflow; you merrily try to add row 5, 6, 7, ... without testing that it is safe to do so.  You're also combining 3 tasks in a single function: store, sort, print.  Overall, not a good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert an integer to the string representation in C.

Use `ltoa()/itoa()/_itoa_s()` or `sprintf()/snprintf()`

Secondly, if its a buffer and not a pointer, then you can't assign to it, you have to copy into it.

NOTE:
Be aware of buffer overruns, prefer the safe versions of all functions. The safe way to use sprintf() if your platform **lacks** snprintf() or _itoa_s() is to (1) avoid unbounded format strings (%s, etc.) and (2) recognize what you are formatting, and its max bounds.

Example, for a 64-bit integer:

Max value:

```
18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

The base 10 ASCII length of this would be 20 characters. Use an order of magnitude larger for a character buffer. I like to use a 1024 length buffer for sprintf() conversions.

```
18446744073709551615 (unsigned) will be approx 20 length.

char buf[1024];
int64_t lval;
sprintf(buf, "%d", lval);
return strdup(buf);  // then dup it, or use strlen to malloc heap mem for your copy
```

Comment: please don't suggest the use of `itoa()`, `ltoa()` or `sprintf()`. They are dangerous.

Comment: only if misused. There are alternatives (`snprintf()`, `asprintf()`) which are safe.

Comment: Yes, I upvoted his answer already. Not everyone is using C99. snprintf()  can be misused to overflow a buffer as well. I don't condone sprintf() if secure options are available.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) (avoid  the old `sprintf` because of possible [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)). On GNU systems, you could use [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) which heap allocates a string (see also [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) which duplicates an existing string).

Comment: +1 always better to prefer snprintf() if you have it available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it can be done

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3
#define M 15

int main( void ) 
{
    static char test[N][M] = { "john", "michael", "simon" };
    unsigned int a[N] = { 234, 432, 489 };
    size_t i;

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        sprintf( test[i] + strlen( test[i] ), " - %u", a[i] );
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        puts( test[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
john - 234
michael - 432
simon - 489
```

Instead of `sprintf` you may use `snprintf` if your compiler supports it. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3
#define M 15

int main( void ) 
{
    static char test[N][M] = { "john", "michael", "simon" };
    unsigned int a[N] = { 234, 432, 489 };
    size_t i;

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        size_t n = strlen( test[i] );
        snprintf( test[i] + n, M - n, " - %u", a[i] );
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        puts( test[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not "may use `snprintf`" but "*should* use `snprintf`"